# EmbeddedId mappedBy Spring Boot 3.1.4 not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Since the update to Spring Boot 3.1.4 i have an issue with mappedBy and EmbeddedId. It worked in all previous Sprint Boot version. Here an example:

Entity with mappedBy to EmbeddedId:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "STATUS")
public class Status {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.globalId")
    private List<StatusLabel> labels;

}
```

Entity with EmbeddedId:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "STATUS_LABELS")
public class StatusLabel {

    @EmbeddedId
    private LabelGlobalId id;

    private String labelname;
    private String shortname;


}
```

EmbeddedId:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class LabelGlobalId implements Serializable {

    private String globalId;
    private String langId;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `@MapsId` annotation instead?

Comment: @M.Deinum, great! Thats it. It solved my issue. In the official doc there is also mentioned to use „@MapsId“! Can you please add it as answer that i can prove it?

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier:~:text=2.2.3.2.1.%C2%A0%40EmbeddedId%20property

Comment: @ZufarSunagatov, thank you very much for your support. How is JPA knowing in your case to map the field to globalId and to to langIf in the EmbeddedId?

Comment: Well you are using Hibernate 6 and are pointing to the Hibernate 3.5 documentation. You might want to check the proper version https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map an id or embedded id one should use the `@MapsId`. I suspect that the `mappedBy` in the relation worked by accident rather then by design.

See also the [relevant section in the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived).

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "STATUS")
public class Status {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany
    @MapsId("globalId")
    private List<StatusLabel> labels;

}
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve this issue, you need to modify the `mappedBy` attribute in the `Status` entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
private List<StatusLabel> labels;
```